# Can I include music in my python game inside the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, winsound

I want to use the winsound module in my text-based python game to play some background music, however I don't want the user to have to put the music files in the same folder as the game just to play it. Is there any way I can include the music in the file, so if I converrt it to an .exe file it will be included?

Some places online say winsound can use the audio data as a string for the winsound.PlaySound function, but how do you convert a .wav file to a string?

Answer (score 0):

```
import winsound

winsound.PlaySound('song.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
time.sleep(1)
```

Replace `song.wav` to any local `.wav` file you want to use.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to store the file information in the code itself so that the user of my program doesn't have to place the sound file in the same directory as the program